# Inverted Selection jQuery + Raphael

Tags: jquery, raphael

Have made this example (round is draggable):
http://softm.org.ua/projects/roundsel-v1/

I need invert selection, i.e. make all other image masked when am dragging this image

All - help me to make an inverted selection of round in Raphael/jQuery, please.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately masking doesn't work with Raphäel at this moment. Maybe you can use Flash to solve your task?

Comment: flash - is that something, that don't work at MACs and what about my clients will write me every time they got access to iMac/iPad? Thanks your :) Masking - works with Raphael :) btw. Idea is -made 2 path - at top and bottom, and change them while dragging. Simply i dont know SVN ideas so well ... so need some help :)